# Is there a way to extract a value from a json field using a processor in apache nifi and substitute that value into another json file?

Tags: java, json, apache-nifi

So I have created a workflow in apache nifi that pulls csv attachments from gmail and converts them to json. What I am stuck on is extracting 3 values (clientip,Country,user-agent) from the json I currently have and replacing those values within another json that I have that will be used to run alerts on another program. I am not sure as to what processors would be used to achieve this. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried playing around with extract attributes and JoltTransformJson but I can not get either of them to work as intended..

First json that I get from converting csv file:

```
{
  "clientip" : "116.255.157.126",
  "Country" : "China",
  "host" : "teachinglaw-prod.uis.georgetown.edu",
  "useragent" : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)",
  "uri" : "//Config_Shell.php"
}
```

Second json I wrote that needs to have ("data","message","data") values updated with first json:

```
    {
"title": "cat7-SQL Injection",
"description": "alert description",
"type": "Internal ",
"source": "Splunk ",
"sourceRef": "Splunk alert ",
"severity": 2,
"tlp": 2,
"artifacts": [{
"dataType": "ip",
"data": "176.121.14.180",
"message": "Belize",
"tags": ["SQL Injection"]
},
{
"dataType": "user - agent",
"data": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/1.0.154.53 Safari/525.19",
"tags": ["SQL Injection"]
}
],
"caseTemplate": "SQL Injection"
}
```

I need to find a processor(s) that will give me this result after values have been merged/substituted :

```
    {
"title": "cat7-SQL Injection",
"description": "alert description",
"type": "Internal ",
"source": "Splunk ",
"sourceRef": "Splunk alert ",
"severity": 2,
"tlp": 2,
"artifacts": [{
"dataType": "ip",
"data": "116.255.157.126",
"message": "China",
"tags": ["SQL Injection"]
},
{
"dataType": "user - agent",
"data": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)",
"tags": ["SQL Injection"]
}
],
"caseTemplate": "SQL Injection"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the `EvaluateJSONPath` processor to extract the desired JSON values to flowfile attributes, and then route to `ReplaceText` and use Expression Language to replace template tokens with the attribute values. For example, given this "input JSON":

```
{
  "clientip" : "116.255.157.126",
  "Country" : "China",
  "host" : "teachinglaw-prod.uis.georgetown.edu",
  "useragent" : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)",
  "uri" : "//Config_Shell.php"
}
```

Your `EvaluateJsonPath` processor should have the following configuration (any property not listed is kept as the default, and the last 3 are "Dynamic Properties" added with the "**+**" button on the top right of the table):

- *Destination*: `flowfile-attribute`
- *ip*: `$.clientip`
- *message*: `$.Country`
- *user_agent*: `$.useragent`

The next processor is a `ReplaceText` processor with the following configuration:

- *Search Value*: `(?s)(^.*$)`
- *Replacement Value*: `{...JSON template below...}`

The JSON template is the following:

```
{
    "title": "cat7-SQL Injection",
    "description": "alert description",
    "type": "Internal ",
    "source": "Splunk ",
    "sourceRef": "Splunk alert ",
    "severity": 2,
    "tlp": 2,
    "artifacts": [{
            "dataType": "ip",
            "data": "<template_ip>",
            "message": "<template_message>",
            "tags": ["SQL Injection"]
        },
        {
            "dataType": "user - agent",
            "data": "<template_user_agent>",
            "tags": ["SQL Injection"]
        }
    ],
    "caseTemplate": "SQL Injection"
}
```

Each value of the form `<template_some_value>` will get matched and the `some_value` piece will get extracted as the capture group referenced by `$2`.

Finally, another `ReplaceText` is used to inject the attribute value into each template token location. The configuration is:

- *Search Value*: `<(template_(\w+))>`
- *Replacement Value*: `${${'$2'}}`

The final output will look like:

[image: Screenshot of flowfile content after value insertion]

Comment: Thank you so much Andy! I followed your steps and it worked perfectly. I tunnel visioned and never thought to use a second replace text for the second json. Thank you!